# Outlook user is sending multiple calendar invites to recipients

Tags: exchange, outlook-2007, iphone, windows-sbs

This only appears to be affecting one user, but this user sends a calendar invite, then starts sending multiple invites there after. We are using Exchange SBS, with the user using Outlook 2007, also the user has an iPhone which he has yet to confirm if he used the device to send the invite.

The problem only seems intermittent but is obviously a problem, I'm not entirely sure if it's Outlook or Exchange.

One more thing I should point out is that the user is based remotely and isn't always in the office, I do have access to Exchange however.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's the iphone.  Restart the device quickly then delete the entry and try again.  I have seen this issue myself.  If you check the headers you will find that the messages are being generated by an SMTP at apple.

Comment: I have yet to find the cause or a perminate solution for this myself either but that will stop the behavior for the time being.  This was a nightmare for us as it happened on a Calendar invite with more then a dozen clients on it.

Answer (score 0):

You should first of all identify wheter this is a server or client problem.

Two tests you should really do:

- Make that user log in to another computer (or ask for his password and log in as him) and send an invite.
- Mak him log in as another user (a test one will do) on his computer and send an invite.

Some random questions:

- How is the user connecting? Outlook? Outlook Anywhere? OWA?
- Which versions of Exchange and Outlook?

Comment: They use Outlook 2007 on their laptop and Mail on their iPhone.

Exchange is SBS 2003